# ASP MVC internal image url to external url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want an `<img src='http://www.exmaple.com/image.jpg'/>` tag in a page.

I want the url to reference to my site, like `<img src='images/image.jpg'/>`

I dont want to download the image to my host, only a reference that points to external site but the url to my internal site.

Is it possible to create a controller to reference to external image?

Comment: If I understand what you mean, you need to create a route in a controller that intercepts the image calls and remotely download the image and pass it to the user. eg. src="external/image.jpg"

Comment: exactly but is there a way not to download the file. only route it

Comment: You would need to intercept the request and download the file yourself and return a `FileResult`

Comment: Re-routing the file url wouldn't be possible. A 302 redirect would work but it would show in the browser the files final location.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src='@Url.Content("~/images/image.jpg")'/>
```

Comment: the "~/images/image.jpg" path does not exist. i want a way to reference this path to external path.

Comment: i want to hide the external link.